# SwiftyAPI - Open multiple accounts

Tags: dropbox-api

I asked a question early in the V2 review process about simultaneous access to multiple accounts. I was told this was supported.

When I tried to call 
     Dropbox.authorizeFromController(MyViewController)

It get's an assertion error   "Client is already authorized"

What is the process to open a second connection  ?

Comment: I believe `Dropbox.authorizeFromController` is only meant for use with a single account. If you need multiple accounts, try using `DropboxAuthManager.authorizeFromController`.

Comment: The DropboxAuthManager works great! I really do not understand why you need the other class ... I do not quite understand the motivation for the sharedAuthManager. What is the motivation for it ?